# fread does not skip empty line when it's the last line of region-to-be-skipped

Tags: r, data.table

In my tab-delimited data file (small sample can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/52k49qwzkplvqcn/hg19.fa.out2.head.tsv)), first 2 lines are header lines which I need to skip, third line is empty and therefore should also be skipped, and actual data starts from line 4. When I try to read it via `fread` with `skip=3` argument:

```
dtRM3 <- fread("hg19.fa.out2.head.tsv", skip=3, sep="\t", header=F)
```

it gives a warning: `Stopped reading at empty line 3, but text exists afterwards (discarded):` - then the warning shows the text of line 4. I don't understand why it's reading empty line 3 while I indicated to skip first 3 lines. If I make line 3 non-empty by putting any characters there, it is skipped correctly. Alternatively, if I tell to skip one more line -

```
dtRM4 <- fread("hg19.fa.out2.head.tsv", skip=4, sep="\t", header=F)
```

it skips correctly first 4 lines and starts from line 5.

Answer (score 2):

The data reads in correctly (7 records, 15 variables with out header) if you run just `fread("hg19.fa.out2.head.tsv")` with out any extra arguments. I can not explain it.

Comment: you're right, specifically for this example I can run `fread` without other arguments. But still I would like to understand why it works the described way...

Comment: @VasilyA I can have a look but can you have a go at improving the question (and title) please to clarify that. See some examples and advice in [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). e.g. "strange" is too vague.